# Using QTQuick with haskell

Tags: qt, haskell

It looks to me that qthaskell is not being actively developed/ is abandoned.

Does it support QtQuick ?

Are there plans / any development in supporting qt 5 ?

Does anyone uses qt with haskell at all, or is gtk2hs the current favorite ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

QtHaskell supports Qt 4.6 and thus QtQuick, at least the early lighthouse build version. Note that this version of QtQuick is completely different from the current QtQuick version; most elements and properties have completely different names.

GTK support for Haskell is being actively maintained. As you have seen for yourself, the same cannot be said about Qt. One of the main reasons is that GHC cannot import foreign C++ code by itself; you need to generate wrapper C code that is then called by GHC, and there isn't a general method for wrapping C++ code as C, so a new tool has to be developed for C++ in this case. So, the "current favorites" for GUI libraries in Haskell are GTK and WxWidgets.

It would be very interesting to use Qt in Haskell, for example because the Qt sockets system could be used to link into FRP (functional reactive programming) libraries, and because Qt has an interface that is very referentially transparent and that supports immutable data structures.

Comment: Last release of qthaskell was sep.2010. and current qt is 4.8.1. Looks like i have no choice but to go with gtk. :(

Comment: @VagifVerdi: wxHaskell might also be an option. It's in very active development and is pretty full-featured.

Comment: By "Qt sockets system" do you mean Qt's "slots and signals"? Using them for FRP, possibly with Haskell, is the first thing I thought when I heard of them. But I'm inexperienced both at Qt and at Haskell, so I'm gratified that someone else had the same idea, if it indeed is the same idea. Here's hoping that someone starts working on this!

Comment: Maybe some day I will have the time to start a generator for this. Not promising anything, however!

Comment: A generator? What do you mean?

Comment: A tool that scans the header files of Qt, and generates binding C code and corresponding Haskell interface files, so that Qt may be used from Haskell.

Answer (score 6):

There is actually a library to use Qt Quick from Haskell, though I didn't (yet) try it myself:

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hsqml-0.1.1

http://www.gekkou.co.uk/software/hsqml/

http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2012-September/103350.html

It is maintained as of now, with the latest release being in september 2012. There is also a demo program published on hackage.

That version doesn't yet support emitting Qt signals from Haskell code, there is however a fork which is supposed to offer that feature:
https://github.com/travitch/hsqml

But the fork appears less maintained than the original package, and in addition the author of the original package stated that he intends to add that feature in the future (and also support Qt5 when it will be available).

**UPDATE** now happily using this library, although it didn't get much traction, it works great for me.